# NodeJS won't serve my static files

Tags: node.js, express

I encountered a lot of instances of my problem, however none of them worked for me. Where is my server root, if both of these paths don't work? Static files aren't found neither under `la-wars` > `public` > `css` > `file`, nor under the more relative `public` > `css` > `file`.

This is how I use express for the purpose:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

And it results in the second 404 result below. With the first one, I had `express.static()` commented out and tried an absolute path in the markup.

[image]

[image]

*EDIT*: The entire entry point app:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = require('express')(),
    ejs = require('ejs'),
    path = require('path'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    util = require('util'),
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    user = require('./models/user.js'),
    formidable = require('formidable'),
    router = express.Router();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
//app.use(require('.middleware/auth.js'));

app.use(require('./routes')(express));

app.listen(port);
```

Comment: Can you post your entire expressJs script?  That will help.

Comment: @user2263572 There you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what the url is you put on your html pages, but from the console's error window, I'm going to guess this (notice extra first argument) solves your problem:

```
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

It seems you use both "/public" (for the js) and "public" (for the css) in your html file. The code above should at least fix one of the two errors.

The call:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

is saying that it could serve your files in the 'public' folder directly, so you can keep this but in the html files remove the "public/" from the urls and begin them with "/" directly.

Comment: @SvetanDimoff edited my post. Basically you just gave a public folder but without its route it would have been considered to be served at the root or `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You will find `slider.js`at the url of `http://localhost:3000/js/slider.js` - that's how it works.